# Xorg intermittently restarts after suspend

Tags: 12.04, xorg, suspend, toshiba-satellite

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba laptop. About one out of every three times, when waking from suspend, it wakes up normally and works for anywhere from 10-45 seconds, then the screen goes black, then it returns to the Xwindows login screen, as if I had done sudo killall -9 Xorg.

Comment: I experience exactly the same bug, on a Lenovo L520 - not as often, but same behaviour.