# Ubuntu 12.04 intermittently fails to wake up from sleep

Tags: 12.04, wakeup

When I put my Ubuntu 12.04 machine into sleep, *sometimes* on waking up, it fails, logs me out, and takes me back to login screen. When I log back in, it tells me some unexpected error happened, but it fails to let me report the bug. This has started to happen recently, but I don't know what triggered it.

```
uname -a Linux [name] 3.2.0-30-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 16:52:48 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The issue seems similar to [Xorg intermittently restarts after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176433/xorg-intermittently-restarts-after-suspend). But in my case I am not sure if it is a Xorg issue. I looked at xorg logs, but didn't notice anything indicating an error.

I know I am not providing a lot of info, but I am not sure where (e.g. which log files) I should seek for more info.